# Why does beautifulsoup return </td> with loads of spaces and new lines?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to run the below code, which seems to me like a normal scraping snippet, that should return the table datas in a list, but it returns with a bunch of white space. I have tried removing the extra characters with strip() and replace(" ",""). Unfortunately, no luck.

Any idea how to clean this? Or is this a html issue on the site I'm trying to access?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import pandas as pd
import csv


url = 'https://www.felvi.hu/felveteli/ponthatarok_statisztikak/friss_statisztikak/!FrissStatisztikak/index.php/friss_statisztikak/szakonkent?filters%5Bsta_iin_id%5D=1475&filters%5Bsta_kar_id%5D='



result = requests.get(url)
html_code = bs(result.text, "html.parser")

table = html_code.find('table', class_ = "center tblc w100 l")

rows = table.find_all('tr')

list_rows = []

for row in rows: 
    row_td = row.find_all('td')
    for i in row:
        print(i)
    str_cells = row_td
    #clean_text = bs(str_cells,"lxml").get_text()
    #list_rows.append(clean_text)
```

Comment: do you want to get the data of the whole table?

Comment: Use View Source and you'll see that these table cells are split into multiple lines with lots of indentation. The browser collapses all the whitespace, but you see it when you view the source with BS4.

Comment: It's not safe to remove all the spaces, because some of them are between attributes in HTML tags.

Comment: Yeah I'd like the whole table, I was thinking of turning it into a dataframe.

Comment: My main issue is with the fact that when I try getting the text from in-between the tags, it still looks horrible, while I know it should be just the strings without spaces and stuff. I don't want to remove the tabs and spaces from the html, if I understand your precaution.

Answer (score 1):

You can get all four tables from that page using the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

dfs = pd.read_html('https://www.felvi.hu/felveteli/ponthatarok_statisztikak/friss_statisztikak/!FrissStatisztikak/index.php/friss_statisztikak/szakonkent?filters%5Bsta_iin_id%5D=1475&filters%5Bsta_kar_id%5D=')
for df in dfs:
    print(df)
```

This will return 4 tables:

```
_______________

    0   1
0   Felhasználónév:     NaN
1   Jelszó:     NaN

_______________

    0   1
0   Belépés Mégsem  Belépés Mégsem

_______________

    0
0   Szűkítési feltételek:
1   Intézményválasztó:
2   ... Állatorvostudományi Egyetem (ATE) András...
3   Karválasztó:
4   ... Állatorvostudományi Egyetem (ATE )

_______________

    0   1   2   3   4
0   Szak    KMF     Jelentkezők     Jelentkezők     Felvettek
1   Szak    KMF     Össz.   Első.   Felvettek
2   állatorvosi     ONA     597     458     116
3   állatorvosi     ONK     231     15  34
4   biológia    ANA     193     60  29
5   biológia    ANK     37  2   1
6   biológus    MNA     43  11  9
7   biológus    MNK     4   0   0
```

Is any of these tables what you're after?

Pandas relevant documentation can be found at https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html

Answer (score 1):

You can get the data from the table with pandas easily

```py
html_code = bs(result.text, "html.parser")

table = html_code.find('table', class_ = "center tblc w100 l")

df = pd.read_html(str(table))
```

You'll get your data in a data frame as follows:

```
             0    1            2            3          4
 0         Szak  KMF  Jelentkezők  Jelentkezők  Felvettek
 1         Szak  KMF        Össz.        Első.  Felvettek
 2  állatorvosi  ONA          597          458        116
 3  állatorvosi  ONK          231           15         34
 4     biológia  ANA          193           60         29
 5     biológia  ANK           37            2          1
 6     biológus  MNA           43           11          9
 7     biológus  MNK            4            0          0
```

Comment: Thank you this looks way better, unfortunately this still returns the whole table into one cell. I checked the len() and it's 1, when it should be 8

Comment: do ```df[0].len()``` it'll give you 8